# Program freezing and not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have written this VBA code that goes through a set of data and aligns specific rows of data together and deletes the rest. I have various columns labeled as below. Whenever "Billed" appears under the "`M`" column, my program records the order number associated with that row under "`B`". It then loops and while the order number under "`B`" is consistent, it moves the notes under "`L`" associated with "Completed" and copies it besides the column and the same under where "Billed" was found. In addition, when it also moves the date under column "`D`" for "Confirmed" associated with that same order number and again adds to the column beside the "Billed" row. The problem I am running into is that none of these rows appear in the same order and also there can be duplicates. If there's a duplicate like the one in second order number for "Confirmed" then the most recent one will be taken and copied over beside "Billed". Any help would be tremendously appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance. Here is an Example:-

```
    B         D            L                                             M
1.467334  4/22/2015                                                    Confirmed
2.467334  4/17/2015     YES Tech swapped out the MGR 13, tested        Completed
3.467334  4/20/2015     4/16 Maint. Billed                             Billed
4.537551  4/15/2015                                                    Confirmed

5.537551  4/14/2015     YES Tech swapped out the MGR 13, tested        Confirmed
6.537551  4/08/2015     4/16 Maint. Billed                             Billed
7.537551  4/14/2015     YES Tech swapped out equipment                 Completed
8.537551  4/08/2015     4/16 Maint. equip.                             Confirmed
```

Required Output:-

```
     B         D             L                    M            Q                                     R           
    3.467334  4/20/2015     4/16 Maint. Billed   Billed   YES swapped out theMGR 13, tested        4/22/2015
    6.537551  4/16/2015     4/16 Maint. Billed   Billed   YES Tech swapped out equipment           4/14/2015
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim LR As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim com As Range

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR Step 1

  ''''This might be confusing but what I am doing here is copying the notes for the "Billed" row and moving to the right. 
  'This part works fine but the rest of the "Do While" loop doesn't.
  If Cells(i, "M").Value = "Billed" Then
    Cells(i, "Q").Value = Cells(i, 12).Value
    Set com = Cells(i, "B")
    Set num = Cells(i, "B").Row

    Do While Cells(i, "B").Value = com
      If Cells(i, "M") = "Completed" Then
        Cells(num, "R").Value = Cells(i, 12).Value
      End If
    Loop

    Do While Cells(i, "B").Value = com
      If Cells(i, "M") = "Confirmed" Then
        Cells(num, "S").Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
      End If
    Loop
  End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
Do While Cells(i, "B").Value = com
  If Cells(i, "M") = "Completed" Then
    Cells(num, "R").Value = Cells(i, 12).Value
  End If
Loop
```

`Do While Cells(i, "B").Value = com` will always be true, because neither `i` nor `com` are changing inside your loop. In some way shape or form, you need to adjust the value of one of those two variables within that loop. <strike>I believe that a simple `i = i + 1` will do what you're after, like this:</strike>

```
Do While Cells(i, "B").Value = com
  If Cells(i, "M") = "Completed" Then
    Cells(num, "R").Value = Cells(i, 12).Value
  End If
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Just realized that won't work, since `i` is the counter in your `For...Next` loop. Instead, try this:

```
r = i
Do While Cells(r, "B").Value = com
  If Cells(r, "M") = "Completed" Then
    Cells(num, "R").Value = Cells(r, 12).Value
  End If
  r = r + 1
Loop
```

You've declared `r`, but never used it, so I usurped it for this loop.

The same holds true for your next `Do While...Loop` block.

A couple of additional thoughts:

1. You're mixing reference between `Cells(i, "M")` and `Cells(i, 12)`. While the compiler doesn't care and can easily interpret that, it's harder for us people types to figure out what column is being referenced - is `M` the 12th letter? No, it's the 13th, so that mean... oh, Column `L`!
2. Use consistent block indention - that also makes your code much easier to read and mentally parse. Again, the compiler doesn't care, but you, or the person maintaining the code after you, will appreciate it.
3. You mention that there's an issue with duplicate order numbers. I'm not seeing that unless the `1.`, `2.`, etc are indicating line numbers instead of decimal values. If this is the case, I'd suggest having your code sort the data in an order that makes sense for your purposes, then have your code written in that sorted order. That way, you can expressly handle the duplicate values - for example if `OrderNum(row) = OrderNum(row-1) then` and check the dates to pick up the newest one.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for helping. That fixed the issue for the first while loop which copies the notes to Column "Q". But the next while loop doesn't seem to work for some reason. It gives me blank for column "R" instead of the dates from the "Confirmed" row. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Also, I was referring to 1., 2., 3., etc. as row numbers on excel spreadsheets. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: For some reason, I am getting an error on line "Set num = Cells(i, "B").Row". It says some type of object error.

Comment: You're trying to `Set` a variable equal to an integer `Cells(i, "B").Row`. You only use `Set` when assigning objects. If you had `Dim num as range`, then you would use `Set`. Change that line to `num = Cells(i, "B").Row`, and it will be fine.